# how do get CSS property value as in CSS files instead of computed ones?

Tags: jquery, css

When I inspect webpages and want to adjust elements whose font-size value are in percentage or `em`, I always have to go through their ancestors to find out on whom those percentage values are based on. Since this scenario happens a lot in my life, I am trying to write some code to make things easier. But the problem is, jQuery's .css() method is only getting computed values, like below.

1. how do I get an element's exact CSS value as in CSS files or `style` tag?
2. Is there any function which works like .offsetParent() and can achieve my original goal? **EDIT:** For clarification, I want to find the nearest ancestor whose font-size property is set in `px`. Like .offsetParent(), which can find the nearest ancestor that is 'positioned'.
3. An off-topic question: in the fiddle below, why is the computed value 19.2000007629395 instead of 19.2 which equals to 16*120%?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yae8qn70/

HTML:

```
<div class='a'>
    <div class='b'>120% font</div>
</div>
Result:<span class='r'></span>
```

css:

```
.a{font-size:16px}
.b{font-size:120%}
```

Js:

$('.r').text($('.b').css('font-size'))

Comment: Sounds like you want to use rem http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem. But if this is only for debugging other webpages, then I guess that is not an option.

Comment: Re 3: floating point error (It's a trivial error, if your value was the mean distance between the earth and the moon, the error is equivalent to about 50 feet)

Comment: I suspect you're trying to do the wrong thing. While it would be technically possible to do it with JavaScript, it would be horrendously slow as you'd have to load in all CSS rules, parse them, and calculate the relevant rules. And only then start applying that CSS. You're also likely to have really buggy code, as it's extremely difficult. CSS gives you much better alternatives - `em`s, `rem`s, etc.

Comment: It is not possible to get computed value other than in pixels. That is how browsers work. Second some new browsers use subpixel font scaling which is good thing and enables smooth font scaling. That is way we have long floats in computed panel.

Comment: Not certain interpreting requirement correctly ? What is expected result of `$('.r').text($('.b').css('font-size'))` ?

Comment: I want it to be '120%'

Comment: @Blowski The real life scenario is, in some very complex multi layered DOM elements, there is an element whose font-size is set to 100%, and one of its grand grand grandparents has its font-size set to 16px, the others are all 100%. I just want to find this parent, but it seems there is no easy way, I have to manually go through its parents one by one, starting from the nearest one.

Comment: @shenkwen My guess is that it's an unnecessarily complicated DOM and/or stylesheet. Trying to get round that by re-inventing bits of the browser is going to be slow (for you, and for end users) and buggy. You're better off spending your time fixing your HTML and CSS. If you *really can't* do this (i.e. because you're not control of the whole thing) then OK, but the solution is going to cause many problems.

Answer (score 1):

No easy method, I'm afraid, but if you're determined, you could do something like the following:

1. Get the stylesheets using, e.g. `var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets;`
2. Iterate through each one.
3. For each style sheet, read the rules `.cssRules`
4. Parse each rule in the array looking for the selector you want.

Obviously, you'll have to implement the CSS cascade in your code. Seems like an awful lot of work, but it's at least theoretically possible

Comment: Thank you. I found a `cssText` property somewhere in the `styleSheets`, which contains actual css text as in CSS files. Although the whole thing is not practically doable, but this is what I am trying to find out. There IS a way to get the actual CSS text.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.r').text(function (_, text) {

    var parent = window.getComputedStyle($('.b').parent()[0], null)
                 .getPropertyValue("font-size");

    var elem = window.getComputedStyle($('.b')[0], null)
               .getPropertyValue("font-size");

    var res = (Math.ceil((parseInt(elem) / parseInt(parent)) * 100));

    return res + "%"

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yae8qn70/1/